# How do i hide password field in google datastudio appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am making a datastudio appscript connector. The user has to provide a username and a password but the passwrod is visible when he is typing in the input field. How do i hide it. Ive tried looking in the document but did not found anything.

```
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
var fields = cc.getFields();
var types = cc.FieldType;
var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;


  config
    .newTextInput()
    .setId('uname')
    .setName('username')
    .setHelpText('Your Database username')
    .setPlaceholder('Enter username')

  config
  .newTextInput() // I want to hide this field
  .setId('pass')
  .setName('pass')
  .setHelpText('Your Database Password')
  .setPlaceholder('Enter Password')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing (July 2021), the `TextInput` widget does not currently support hidden characters. This has been reported on Google's Issue Tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187082357

If you really want Google to prioritize this issue make sure to star it (commenting alone has little to no impact, its the star count that matters).

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know. Is there any other way I can hide the password field?

Comment: @user14597035 None that I know of.